# Are these right component to operate spark on yarn?

Tags: hadoop, apache-spark

I'm studing about spark on yarn. I already working wordcount on yarn, and I'm trying to work "spark-shell --master yarn-client". But I found there are problem in yarn, so I'm considering several things to check. Could you let me know these daemon are right to operate spark on yarn? Are there any unnecessary or missing daemon?

From left, Master's daemon   -   slave1's daemon   -   slave2's daemon
[image]

I use hadoop 2.7.2 and spark 1.5.2.
thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yep, everything is fine in your cluster!

You have all 3 components required for running Spark jobs:

1. **HDFS** | NameNode, SecondaryNamenode (Master services) and DataNode, DataNode (Slave services)
2. **YARN** | ResourceManager (Master service) and NodeManager, NodeManager (Slave services)
3. **Spark** | Master (Master service) and Worker, Worker (Slave services)

**Jps** is just a tool which provides information about all Java processes of current user